# JS defined method is equal to NaN in only one part of statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, methods, nan

I'm building part of a clicker that allows you to make a new object that holds a price, price increment and money per second. I've made a prototype that has an If statement that checks if you have enough money for purchase. Inside that If statement is a while loop that makes sure a counter stops when you've reached max money.

The problem is i'm using a method called addMps(money per sec) and it tells how much money is added per second. In the first part of the If statement the addMps method works fine but in the second it returns not a number. With just a number or a variable works fine. Any suggestions?

heres my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>clicker testing</title>
      <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
/*    $(".test").click(function() {
 if(amount >= testPrice) {
  memory -= testPrice;
   testPrice += 25;
    memoryPerSec+= 10;
     $(".logo").text("logo plus 10mps: " + logoPrice + "memory");
     memoryPerSecUpdate();
function logo() {
 if(memory < maxMemory) {
  memory+= 10;
   counterUpdate();
    setTimeout(logo, 1000);
     }
      }
       setTimeout(logo, 0);
 }
 else {
  alert("not enough memory");
}
});*/
var money = 200;
 var maxMoney = 300;
  var mps = 0;
function updateCounters() {
  $(".money").text("money: " + money);
   $(".mps").text("money per sec: " + mps);
    $(".max").text("max money: " + maxMoney);
}
   function clicker(addPrice, addPriceIncrement, addMps) {
        this.addPrice = addPrice;
         this.addPriceIncrement = addPriceIncrement; 
          this.addMps = addMps;
   }
   var stuff = new clicker(100, 25, 10);
clicker.prototype.buy = function() {
 if(money >= this.addPrice) {
  money -= this.addPrice;
   this.addPrice += this.addPriceIncrement;
    mps += this.addMps;
     updateCounters();
function max() {
 if(money < maxMoney) {
  money += this.addMps;
   updateCounters();
    setTimeout(max, 1000);
     }
      }
       setTimeout(max, 0);
 }
 else {
  alert("not enough memory");
}
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateCounters();
   $(".stuff").click(function() {
    stuff.buy();
  });
});
</script>
  </head>
<body style="text-decoration: underline; font-family: verdana;">
  <div class="stuff">stuff</div>
  <div class="money"></div>
  <div class="mps"></div>
  <div class="max"></div>
  <h4>go ahead an click stuff then change this.addMps to a number in the max() function and it works:<br>
  p.s its on line 56
  </h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Within your function `max()` you are trying to use `this.addMps` which is `undefined` because `this` doesn't refer to the `stuff` object.  Use `stuff.addMps` instead. Also: fix the indenting in your code, it is very hard to read as is, very hard to see where the various blocks end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `this` is not the same thing inside a function, it gets redefined, so you have to put it into another variable, like this `var self = this;`.  See below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>clicker testing</title>
      <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
/*    $(".test").click(function() {
 if(amount >= testPrice) {
  memory -= testPrice;
   testPrice += 25;
    memoryPerSec+= 10;
     $(".logo").text("logo plus 10mps: " + logoPrice + "memory");
     memoryPerSecUpdate();
function logo() {
 if(memory < maxMemory) {
  memory+= 10;
   counterUpdate();
    setTimeout(logo, 1000);
     }
      }
       setTimeout(logo, 0);
 }
 else {
  alert("not enough memory");
}
});*/
var money = 200;
 var maxMoney = 300;
  var mps = 0;
function updateCounters() {
  $(".money").text("money: " + money);
   $(".mps").text("money per sec: " + mps);
    $(".max").text("max money: " + maxMoney);
}
   function clicker(addPrice, addPriceIncrement, addMps) {
        this.addPrice = addPrice;
         this.addPriceIncrement = addPriceIncrement; 
          this.addMps = addMps;
   }
   var stuff = new clicker(100, 25, 10);
clicker.prototype.buy = function() {
 if(money >= this.addPrice) {
  money -= this.addPrice;
   this.addPrice += this.addPriceIncrement;
    mps += this.addMps;
     updateCounters();
var self = this;
function max() {
 if(money < maxMoney) {
  money += self.addMps;
   updateCounters();
    setTimeout(max, 1000);
     }
      }
       setTimeout(max, 0);
 }
 else {
  alert("not enough memory");
}
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateCounters();
   $(".stuff").click(function() {
    stuff.buy();
  });
});
</script>
  </head>
<body style="text-decoration: underline; font-family: verdana;">
  <div class="stuff">stuff</div>
  <div class="money"></div>
  <div class="mps"></div>
  <div class="max"></div>
  <h4>go ahead an click stuff then change this.addMps to a number in the max() function and it works:<br>
  p.s its on line 56
  </h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as written, but I'm going with the assumption that the variable `money` sometimes can have values that are not a number, such as

1. NaN
2. undefined
3. null
4. "This is a string"

I your case you are mostly concerned about NaN (Not a Number), and not discussing how you ended up with that value, the bottom line is that you will have to test for it in some way

You can either put the test into each of the conditions, or you can deal with it in one place, for example by making you logic so it works if NaN and having no money is the same, which can be done like

```
var money == CalculateMoney() || 0;
```

where the '|| 0' make whatever you want the default value to be in case CalculateMoney returns any of 'NaN', undefined, null, false or zero -- which all evaluates to false.

However you will still have to do something special if your funcion could return "This is a string" etc